# Silverstripe: Excluding current page from list of the parent's children

Tags: silverstripe

Using Silverstripe's "ChildrenOf" syntax, I've been successfully able to list all children of a page's parent. It's being used in a "see also" style list on a page.

I'd like to exclude the current page from the list but unsure how to determine which is the same as the current page, as within the control loop I'm in the parent's scope. Any ideas? Here's a pseudocode of what I'm doing:

```
<% control ChildrenOf(page-url) %>
    <!-- Output some stuff, like the page's $Link and $Title -->
<% end_control %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a built-in page control for this, so to exclude the current page from your list:

```
<% control ChildrenOf(page-url) %>
    <% if LinkOrCurrent = current %>
        <!-- exclude me -->
    <% else %>
       <!-- Output some stuff, like the page's $Link and $Title -->
    <% end_if %>
<% end_control %>
```

see http://doc.silverstripe.org/sapphire/en/reference/built-in-page-controls#linkingmode-linkorcurrent-and-linkorsection

**UPDATE**

as you mentioned in your comment below that you'd like to use the $Pos control, you need to filter the dataobjectset before iterating over it.
add the following to your Page_Controller class:

```
function FilteredChildrenOf($pageUrl) {
    $children = $this->ChildrenOf($pageUrl);
    if($children) {
        $filteredChildren = new DataObjectSet();
        foreach($children as $child) {
            if(!$child->isCurrent()) $filteredChildren->push($child);
        }
        return $filteredChildren;
    }
}
```

then replace 'ChildrenOf' in your template by 'FilteredChildrenOf':

```
<% control FilteredChildrenOf(page-url) %>
//use $Pos here
<% end_control
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually found this, but was stuck when I tried to display the results in sets of 3. The $Pos variable was no longer useful as I couldn't rely on it's position. Is there a way to dynamically count the items in order to put a closing/opening LI every third item?

Answer (score 2):

In Silverstripe 3.1 you can use a method like this -

```
<% loop $Parent.Children %>
    <% if $LinkingMode != current %>
        <!-- Output some stuff, like the page's $Link and $Title , $Pos etc -->
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

This way you can list all parent's children pages.

See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/templates/common_variables/